# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in Insomnia when trying to delete using http

Tags: javascript, express, mern

I am fairly new to using Express and I am trying to set up the Delete function for my database. I am using the MERN stack. All of my CRUD operations work when I test them with Insomnia, except for the Delete operation.

This is the code block that seems to be giving me a problem.

```
router.route('/:id').delete((res, req) => {
    Post.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
        .then(() => res.json('Post deleted'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```

**RETURNS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**

The thing that is throwing me is that this code block grabs the `req.params.id` without problem.

```
router.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
    Post.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(post => res.json(post))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```

If someone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the params matters here.

First **req**, then **res**, and if necessary **next**.

The correct order is:

```
router.route('/:id').delete((req, res) => {
```

A good official guide:
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking at this for so long, I didn't even notice that they are flipped!

Comment: Great! If this fixes your problem, please select the answer as the correct one so others can benefit from this too. :)